# How to display a gallery of images of a product after clicking on the first image?

Tags: python, django

So in short, I have a ListView in Django which displays pictures with tables on the website. Then I have a DetailView where I am placing a second webpage to use with slugs but I guess my logic is wrong.
I want to be able to click on a particular picture/ table and this would redirect me to another page( possible created with slug) where I can display more pictures of the same table. I have created everything so far but I am thinking my logic is wrong. You don't have to write code, just please explain what is the correct way of doing it since I am doing it for the first time.

First I created a Categories model which lists categories such as: tables, kitchens, wardrobes, bedrooms. I then created Image category where I would have title and image and so on but this was okay for one of the views but for this one I want to display multiple pictures as I mentioned and I saw some code which enabled me to have multiple  images.

views.py

```
    class TableCategoryListView(ListView):
        model = Images
        template_name = 'main/projects/tables.html'
        context_object_name = 'category_images'
    
        queryset = Images.objects.filter(category__category_title="tables")
    
    
    class TablesDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Images
        template_name = "main/projects/tables_slug.html"
```

url.py

```
    path('proekti/masi/', TableCategoryListView.as_view(), name='tables'),
    path('proekti/masi/<slug:slug>', TablesDetailView.as_view(), name='table'),
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title


class Images(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=50,
    )

    category_image = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    slug = models.SlugField(
        null=True,
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Images, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    image = models.ImageField()

    order = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.menu

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order',)
```

I read this would help me to easily add multiple pictures.

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class ImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Images

    class Media:
        js = (
            '/static/js/jquery-latest.js',
            '/static/js/ui.base.js',
            '/static/js/ui.sortable.js',
            '/static/js/menu-sort.js',
        )


class PhotoAlbumInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PhotoAlbum


admin.site.register(
    Images,
    inlines=[PhotoAlbumInline],
    form=ImagesForm,
    list_filter=('category',),
    search_fields=('title',)
)

"""
/* menu-sort.js */

jQuery(function($) {
    $('div.inline-group').sortable({
        /*containment: 'parent',
        zindex: 10, */
        items: 'div.inline-related',
        handle: 'h3:first',
        update: function() {
            $(this).find('div.inline-related').each(function(i) {
                if ($(this).find('input[id$=name]').val()) {
                    $(this).find('input[id$=order]').val(i+1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('div.inline-related h3').css('cursor', 'move');
    $('div.inline-related').find('input[id$=order]').parent('div').hide();
});
"""
```

template tables.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block page_content %}
    {% load static %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/masi.css' %}">

    <div class="row">
{% for image in object_list %}
            {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:1 %}
                <div class="column" style="background-color: whitesmoke">
                    <a href="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ image.category_image.url }}" alt="pic"></a>
                    <p>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}


    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

template tables_slug.html --> where I would want to display all the images of a particular table with it doesn't show me one of the tables and doesn't show all the images I have uploaded in the admin page.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block page_content %}

    {% for image in category_images %}
        <div>
            <h2>{{ object.title }} </h2>
            <img src="{{ object.category_image.url }}" alt="pic">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.I just solved the problem I believe with simpler code.
I was missing "related_names" in the model for the relation.

models.py

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(
        Images,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="child_images",
        )

    image = models.ImageField()

    order = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.menu

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order',)
```

and for the template then: tables_slug.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block page_content %}
    {% load static %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/masi.css' %}">

    {% for image in image.child_images.all %}

            <div class="column">
                <p>
                    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="pic">
                </p>
            </div>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You can do this:

In your TableCategoryListView, override the get_context_data like so:

```
class TableCategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Images
    template_name = 'main/projects/tables.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_images'
    
class TableCategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Images
    template_name = 'main/projects/tablesdetail.html'
    context_object_name = 'detail_cat_img'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TableCategoryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['detail_category'] = Images.objects.all() # this gives you all the items from the Images model
        context['xtr_images'] = PhotoAlbum.objects.all() # the logic to render only those photos related to the current view goes here. You have to figure this out yourself
        
        return context # this returns the two objects above xtr_images and detailcategory
```

You can use the slice operator to determine number of images to show per page either in your views or on the template itself like so:

```
Entry.objects.all()[:5] # prints four images
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Do you mean {{ image.image.url }} ? I tried adding 
    context_object_name = 'image' to the TAbleDEtailView and changed the model to PhotoAlbum since, It was Image but I am extracting those other pictures from PhotoAlbum model but still no result.

Comment: Correct. Updated answer.